# Fabricating cyclic dependencies with Fabrication [fabrication_gem]

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, fabrication-gem

Okay, I didn't create this code, but I do need to find a good way to test it.  We have been using factory_girl and minitest, but have a number of issues.  I'm hoping to be able to move to Rspec and the Fabrication gems to setup some new tests, however I've run into a problem with cyclic dependencies.  We have something like the following:

```
class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
  :validates has_inner?

  def has_inner?
    # Make sure we have an inner object
  end
end

class Inner < ActiveRecord::Base
  :belongs_to :owner
end
```

And I have Fabricators for each, something like:

```
Fabricator(:owner) do
  inner
end

Fabricator(:inner) do
end
```

Anyone have any ideas on how I can pull this off?  Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any relationship defined from `Owner` to `Inner`. Is it a `has_many`? A little more details would be great.

Comment: So, there isn't any specific relationship from Owner to Inner other than the validation that checks for a innner_id and postgres checking the relationship as it is written to the database.

Does that answer your question?